# Dropdown menu php

Tags: php, css, drop-down-menu

Anyone can tell me what's wrong with these code...
I can't make sub menu to be shown...

I think my mistake at the part where I call sub menu from database. But I checked, there is nothing wrong..

maybe there are some mistake at css. but I don't know...

php code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo"css/copy.css" ?>" type="text/css" />
</head>
<?php include "koneksi.php"?>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <?php
            /*where I select main menu from table mainmemnu*/
            $main = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainmenu WHERE aktif='Y'");

            while($r=mysql_fetch_array($main))
            {
                echo"<li><a href='$r[link]'><span>$r[nama_menu]</span></a>";

                /*where I select sub menu from table submenu*/
                $sub = mysql_query
                ("SELECT * FROM submenu, mainmenu WHERE submenu.id_main = mainmenu.id_main AND submenu.id_main=$r[id_main]");

                $jml = mysql_num_rows($sub);

                if($jml > 0)
                {
                    echo"<div><ul>";

                    while($w = mysql_fetch_array($sub))
                    {
                        echo
                        "<li>
                            <a href='$w[link_sub]'>
                            <span>
                                &#187; $w[nama_sub]
                            </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>";
                    }
                    echo"</ul></div></li>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo"</li>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font: 14px Helvetica, San-Serif;}
#page-wrap{width: 800px; margin: 0px auto; padding-left: 419px;}
a { text-decoration: none; }
ul { list-style: none; }
p { margin: 15px 0; }

/* Level One */
ul.dropdown{position: relative;}
ul.dropdown li{font-weight: bold; float: left; zoom: 1; background: #ccc;}
ul.dropdown a:hover{color: #000;text-decoration: none;}
ul.dropdown a:active{color: #222;}
ul.dropdown li a{display: block; padding: 4px 8px; border-right: 1px solid #333; color:#222;}
ul.dropdown li:last-child a{border-right: none;}
ul.dropdown li.hover, ul.dropdown li:hover{background: #ffa500; color: black; position: relative; z-index: 9;}
ul.dropdown li.hover a{color: black;}

/* Level Two */

ul.dropdown ul{width: 220px; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0;}
ul.dropdown ul li{font-weight: normal; background: #DCDCDC; color: #000; z-index: 9; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; float: none;}
ul.dropdown ul li a{border-right:none; width:100%; display: inline-block;}
```

the sub menu won't come out when i bring cursor on the menu...

Comment: Can you post the source HTML that you are getting from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to see what the HTML generated by the code looks like, but IMO, you are using way too many divs, spans, tags that are not needed..

Check out if this jsfiddle can help you out, its made purely out of HTML & CSS.

This is the part of the CSS you might be missing.

```
ul.dropdown > li > ul {
    display: none;
}

ul.dropdown > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x9D37/

Comment: thx for the answer maltray...
but. when I ran your jsfiddle code, child menus just shown directly. It isn't hidden till I bring cursor on the parents, like what it shown in jsfiddle...

Comment: oh sorry... it's my fault forget to insert css in html

Comment: Thats why I asked to see the HTML generated, I dont think echo"something" would work, rather throw a PHP error. PS: Glad it worked for ya

Answer (score 0):

You need a javascript to manipulate the block you want to see when hovering over a tag.
You cannot hover over a hidden tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the css that will make the child div display.
Basically it comes down to:

```
/*hiding initially*/
.dropdown li ul
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
/*display selectively*/
.dropdown li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}
```